# Fatal Error:sorry, too many clients already in getting many query from db

Tags: java, database, swing, hibernate

i've problem with connection size...
i know that the problem from where...
i've heavy loading on my program,and i have to getting many query from DB(postgres used here)...
the hibernate connection pool size didn't help me too...
that's a stability problem at first,but when my db getting bigger and bigger this problem shown quicker too..
is exist any solution for this problem?
as the console says:

> ERROR: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class DBUtilU {
private static Session scss;
private static SessionFactory sfactory;
static {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Userdetails.class);
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Code.class);
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Messages.class);
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Comments.class);
    cfg.configure();
    new SchemaExport(cfg);
    sfactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

}

public static boolean saveObject(Object object) {
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        scss.save(object);
        scss.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        scss.getTransaction().rollback();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean updateObject(Object object) {
    try {
//          scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
//          scss.beginTransaction();
        scss.update(object);
//          scss.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        scss.getTransaction().rollback();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean removeObject(Object object) {
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        scss.delete(object);
        scss.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        scss.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return false;
}

public static Userdetails loadUser(String username, String password) {
    Userdetails userdetails;
    try {
        scss = sfactory.openSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Userdetails where username=\'" + username
                + "\' and password=\'" + password + "\'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        userdetails = (Userdetails) queryResult.list().get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return userdetails;

}

        public static Userdetails loadUserForMsging(String username) {
    Userdetails userdetails;
    try {
        scss = sfactory.openSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Userdetails where username=\'" +username+"\'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        userdetails = (Userdetails) queryResult.list().get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return userdetails;

}

        public static Code loadCode(String Path) {
    Code code;
    try {
        scss = sfactory.openSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Code where fileName=\'" + Path + "\'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        code = (Code) queryResult.list().get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return code;

}

public static void Ratermethod(String filename,int rate) {
    Code code = null;
    try {
        scss = sfactory.openSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Code where fileName=\'" + filename + "\'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        code = (Code) queryResult.list().get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int nor=code.getNORaters()+1;
    int prate=code.getRating();
    int nrate = ((((nor-1)*prate)+rate)/nor);
    code.setNORaters(nor);
    code.setRating(nrate);
    DBUtilU.updateObject(code);
    scss.getTransaction().commit();

}

        public static void AddCmtmethod(String filename,String cm,String cmplacer)         {
    Code code = null;
    try {
        scss = sfactory.openSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Code where fileName=\'" + filename + "\'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        code = (Code) queryResult.list().get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

            Comments cmt =new Comments(cm,cmplacer);
            cmt.setTargetCode(code);
            DBUtilU.updateObject(code);
            DBUtilU.saveObject(cmt);
//      scss.getTransaction().commit();

}

public static boolean LogoutUser() {
    try {
                if (scss.isOpen()) {
                    scss.getTransaction().commit();
                }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        scss.getTransaction().rollback();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isUser(String username,String pass) {
    Userdetails userdetails = null;
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Userdetails where username=\'" + username
                + "\' and password=\'" + pass + "\'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        userdetails = (Userdetails) queryResult.list().get(0);
        if (userdetails != null)
            scss.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    scss.getTransaction().commit();
    return false;
}

        public static boolean UniqueUser(String username) {
    Userdetails userdetails = null;
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Userdetails where username=\'" + username +     "\'";
                    Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        userdetails = (Userdetails) queryResult.list().get(0);
        if (userdetails != null)
            scss.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    scss.getTransaction().commit();
    return false;
}

public static List<String> ListOfUsers() {
    List<String> Userlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "select username from Userdetails";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        for(Object c : queryResult.list())
            Userlist.add((String)c);
                    scss.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return Userlist;
}

public static List<Code> searchCodeTags(String tags) {
    List<Code> codelist = new ArrayList<Code>();
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Code where Tags='" + tags+"'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        for(Object c : queryResult.list())
            codelist.add((Code)c);
                    String query2 = "from Code where Tags2='" + tags+"'";
                    Query queryResult2 = scss.createQuery(query2);
                    for(Object c : queryResult2.list())
            codelist.add((Code)c);
                    scss.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return codelist;
}

        public static List<Code> searchCodeAll(String all) {
    List<Code> codelist = new ArrayList<Code>();
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Code where Tags='" + all+"'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        for(Object c : queryResult.list())
            codelist.add((Code)c);
                    String query2 = "from Code where Tags2='" + all+"'";
                    Query queryResult2 = scss.createQuery(query2);
                    for(Object c : queryResult2.list())
            codelist.add((Code)c);
                    String query3 = "from Code where CodeLang='" + all+"'";
                    Query queryResult3 = scss.createQuery(query3);
                    for(Object c : queryResult3.list())
            codelist.add((Code)c);
                    String query4 = "from Code where OwnerName='" + all+"'";
                    Query queryResult4 = scss.createQuery(query4);
                    for(Object c : queryResult4.list())
            codelist.add((Code)c);
                    scss.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return codelist;
}
                public static List<Code> searchCodePrj(String prj) {
    List<Code> codelist = new ArrayList<Code>();
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Code where PrjName='" + prj+"'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        for(Object c : queryResult.list())
            codelist.add((Code)c);
                    scss.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return codelist;
}
            public static List<Code> searchCodeLang(String lang) {
    List<Code> codelist = new ArrayList<Code>();
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Code where CodeLang='" + lang+"'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        for(Object c : queryResult.list())
            codelist.add((Code)c);
                    scss.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return codelist;
}

        public static List<Messages> MessageLoader(String Reciever) {
    List<Messages> MSGlist = new ArrayList<Messages>();
    try {
        scss = sfactory.getCurrentSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
                    String query = "from Messages where Reciever='" + Reciever + "'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        for(Object c : queryResult.list())
            MSGlist.add((Messages)c);
                    scss.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return MSGlist;
            }
}
```

Consloe:

> Jun 22, 2013 2:41:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 53300
>   Jun 22, 2013 2:41:36 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   ERROR: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to close your session when you are done with them. Nowhere in your code I see

```
session.close();
```

---

For example here:

```
public static Code loadCode(String Path) {
    Code code;
    try {
        scss = sfactory.openSession();
        scss.beginTransaction();
        String query = "from Code where fileName=\'" + Path + "\'";
        Query queryResult = scss.createQuery(query);
        code = (Code) queryResult.list().get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

You must close the session. So, add finally block:

```
    finally {
        scss.close();
    }
```

Comment: that's true,but method with this shape can be instantly update their attributes,and if i closed their session,how can i update them?

Comment: Not entirely true. When you call `openSession()` a new session is created, and the pointer to the previous one is lost, but it's still alive!

Comment: what's difference between getTransaction().commit() And close()?
is there any solution exist?

Comment: >org.hibernate.HibernateException: update is not valid without active transaction
 at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.update(Unknown Source)
 at DB.DBUtilU.updateObject(DBUtilU.java:55)
 at GUI.MessagingPage.jButton1ActionPerformed(MessagingPage.java:151)
 at GUI.MessagingPage.access$000(MessagingPage.java:23)
 at GUI.MessagingPage$2.actionPerformed(MessagingPage.java:88)
with your solution i get this error at start...
:(

Comment: Transaction commit just commits the changes you have made so far to the database. It guarantees that your data stays in consistent state, that the transaction is atomic and durable (read about ACID properties). That does not have to do anything with managing of the sessions, creation or closing of them.

Comment: Regarding the error, you need to restructure the code better. Create a pool of sessions (maybe 10), and for each transaction take one from the pool, commit the transaction and return the session to the pool. Synchronize it and wait for the session if there is no free session in the pool. Database programming is not easy and you should plan your code architecture good. And do not use static variables and methods... There are many things wrong with your code but as I said, the original problem you have is because you have too many open connections to the Database.